# Pass argument to parameter

Tags: java, android, methods, parameter-passing

I creat a class "Item" that implements Parcelable and set his constratctor

```
public Item(Parcel in) {
    this.mName = in.readString();
    this.mFilePath = in.readString();
    this.mId = in.readInt();
    this.mLength = in.readInt();
    this.mTime = in.readLong();
}
```

My problem is that when i use that class i dont know what to pass in parameter like exemple bellow:

```
 Item item = new  Item(//What to put her!); 
    item.setId(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
    item.setName(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_NAME)));
    item.setFilePath(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_FILE_PATH)));
    item.setLength(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_LENGTH)));
    item.setTime(c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_TIME_ADDED))); 
return item;
```

Comment: Add a second constructor with the semantics you need.

Comment: but i want to use that specific constructor ! @Henry

Comment: I don't understand why you would want that. But in this case you have to build up a parcel with the correct structure manually.

Comment: can you show me a simple. @Henry

Answer (score 0):

[Parcel.writeStringArray](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeStringArray(java.lang.String%5B%5D))

use Parcel.writeStringArray to bundle your Strings then past it to the constructor

Answer (score 0):

You can have an other Constructor in the Item Class

```
public Item(mName,mFilepath,mId,mLength,mTime) {
    this.mName = mname;
    this.mFilePath = mFilepath;
    this.mId = mId;
    this.mLength = mLength;
    this.mTime = mTime;
}
```

In Your activity Initialise all the fiels in the item

```
 int id=(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("_id")));
 String name =   
  (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_NAME)));
 String filePath=     
  (c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_FILE_PATH)));
 int length=     
  (c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_RECORDING_LENGTH)));
 double time =    
  (c.getLong(c.getColumnIndex(DBHelperItem.COLUMN_NAME_TIME_ADDED)));
```

Now you can create a new item using above fields

Item item = new  Item(id, name,filePath,lenfth,time  );

Here is my example of using Parcelable: https://github.com/riyaza15/ParcelableDemo`enter code here`

Answer (score 0):

Item.java

```
public class Item {

    private String mName;
    private String mFilePath;
    private int mId;
    private int mLength;
    private long mTime;

    public Item(Parcel in) {
        this.mName = in.readString();
        this.mFilePath = in.readString();
        this.mId = in.readInt();
        this.mLength = in.readInt();
        this.mTime = in.readLong();
    }
}
```

Parcel.java(according to what we can see from your code, it should contain below methods)

```
public class Parcel {

    public String readString() {

        //read a string
        return null;
    }

    public int readInt() {

        //read an int
        return 0;
    }

    public long readLong() {

        //read a long
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Test.java(which your main method resides)

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        Parcel p = new Parcel();

        /*Pass the parcel like this*/

        Item item = new Item(p);

        /*
         * 
         * Rest of the code
         * 
         * */
    }
}
```

Maybe your method definitions differ from the code provided. You should change them accordingly.